# sleeping in a thread without causing runOnUiThread to sleep

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-sleep

I have a thread in my android app, this thread has to sleep for a certain time in order to waiting some results which will be set by the `runOnUiThread` thread, the problem is when i tried to make the thread sleeps for a portion of time the `runOnUiThread` sleeps with it too and so it doesn't perform any processing till the other thread wakes up although `runOnUiThread` is exists in another separated thread.

that's my code:
The thread that contains the `runOnUiThread` :

```
Thread xbmc = new Thread (){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                     System.out.println("one");// working perfectly
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            try { 
                       System.out.println("two");// not work till the other thread wakes up
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });
   }
 };
         xbmc.start();
```

And this is the Thread that I make sleeps:

```
    display = false;
    Thread wait = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int d = 0;
            while (d != 20) {
                if (wake_up) {
                    display = true;
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                d++;
            }

            if (!display) {
                display = true;
            }
        }
    });
    wait.start();

    while(!display){}// infinite loop waits for the thread to finish it's looks or something breaks it, and there is no something can break it but the `runOnUiThread` processing results
```

Comment: Your problem is " while(!display){}" which is blocking your UI Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missunderstanding some basic concepts about `Thread`s. Your threads, as you defined them, seem (moreless) ok, they are not blocking your UI as they're running in the background. What **is** blocking your UI is the `while (!display) {}` loop.

You're waiting here until your thread modifies that value, which I guess is not what you're trying to achieve. You'd need to define some other way of doing this, like for example, append the `while (!display)` content code block to the `Thread`.